# Can IMPORTRANGE update/expand on the #2 sheet as rows are added to the source range?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, row

I am managing a client list (about 300 rows of data). I currently have set the master list up as the source to my #2 sheet where I am tracking additional data. When we add a row to the Master list, I need the #2 sheet to create a new row so that adding a new client doesn't skew all of our past data. I additionally want to have minimal maintenance and would like sheet #2 to stay up-to-date as we update the source sheet. Any recommendations on how to achieve this?

I tried testing the importrange function as is but when I add a new row in the middle of the list (very common thing to happen) the correlating data fields don't move with their row labels...

Answer (score 0):

there's a ***very crude approach*** if you wish to try and link your `dynamically shifting` importrange data with the `static` data fields you are entering in your sheet #2. Its upto you to decide if this approach is something that's feasible for ya.

- As shown in the screenshot maintain a column to accommodate sequence
  of numbers. when ever you insert a new row in b/w existing rows
  increment the existing max value in that row by `1`. 11 and 12 are
  newly inserted rows in the screenshot.
- Also to not get confused by what number should be entered when new
  row is created, you can see the cell C1 showing the max value in
  Column A. so you just enter 13 next.
- C1 formula: `=max(A2:A)`
- Now coming to the second sheet you have a `static sequence of numbers`
  in column A. Column B has the following formula which links the data
  to respective numbers irrespective of rows addition at random spots in
  source sheet.

B2 formula: `=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ax,IMPORTRANGE("[SPREADSHEET ID","Sheet2!A:B"),2,)))))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation, it still isn't inserting/creating a new row where one is being created on the source sheet..... [Loom] (https://www.loom.com/share/67983e989a0c4caaab3886e220899bd7) Did I miss something in the precious directions you shared or is there something additional I need to do?

Comment: I've seen the vid and am not sure how much of the above steps were replicated successfully. anyways the above approach is never meant to add rows automatically in the midst of target book or so. all it can do is link the dynamic parts of sheet 1 with static parts of sheet 2. If possible please do share two sample sheets with some minimal demo data and I can can work those up and maybe then you'll get an idea of what I am referring to,

Comment: Source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QzBRdjxSXrR4OfTs_8l1CxzttZLtBiZ2yLt5365oa9A/edit#gid=816040532

Second Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1my9gJ1xJ_dXIMFs-qKWoFcizkVaJKPC0unl0DV0dxsg/edit#gid=0

Comment: The shared sheets have restrictive access!

Comment: Added formula in `Cell B2` in this [tab here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1my9gJ1xJ_dXIMFs-qKWoFcizkVaJKPC0unl0DV0dxsg/edit#gid=878559795). I've also added dummy new rows in the midst of source sheet (highlighted in yellow) to showcase how they reflect in destination sheet (https://i.imgur.com/qvSesYS.png)

Comment: Thank you - I'm confused though because in order for your formula to function, you removed my import range functions which are required for the usage of this sheet... is there a way to accomplish what I asked in my original question with my current formulas in place?

Comment: Within the `importrange` function just the [spreadsheet ID](https://cdn-6122bbc2c1ac18b2a0336205.closte.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/image-4.png.webp) is enough; not the entire spreadsheet URL. it looked redundant & that is the change I made. nowhere your original functions are changed to something out of the box!!

Comment: I think we have a disconnect somewhere.... you added a tab and removed my formulas from the tab you were working on. unless you were trying to imply I needed a duplicate tab for your function to work? Either way this has not solved my problem in any way...

Comment: I created and worked on a duplicate tab so that your main tab data+formulas remain undisturbed and also for the very reason that duplicate tab can be easily discarded off if the workaround is not feasible for you. Yeah it's best we drop this off here.

Comment: oh ok, I made that copy so you could edit directly that was part of the confusion. I appreciate you taking the time to share this insights - I do need the importrange to still function so I'll continue my search, thank you!